# "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" solucionar problema al consumir web service

Tags: javascript, jquery, webservice

estoy consumiendo este servicio, que me esta dando el error: "has been blocked by CORS policy: Cannot parse Access-Control-Allow-Methods response header field in preflight response"

```
 var settings = {
            "url": "https://farm3.sat.gob.gt/atc-ws/rest/privado/atc/consultarAtcPorContenedor",
            "method": "POST",
            "timeout": 3000,
            "headers": {
                "Authorization": "Basic dfdsafasfsafa",
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                "Accept": "application/json;charset=utf-8"
            },
            "data": JSON.stringify({"noContenedor": "<%= id%>"})
        };

        $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
            console.log(response);
            document.getElementById("mensajeatc").innerHTML = response.mensaje;


            if (response.codigo == 1) {

                document.getElementById("noAtc").innerHTML = response.operacion.atc[0].noAtc;
                document.getElementById("estado").innerHTML = response.operacion.atc[0].estado;
                document.getElementById("descripcionEstado").innerHTML = response.operacion.atc[0].descripcionEstado;
                document.getElementById("fechaEstadoRegistrado").innerHTML = response.operacion.atc[0].fechaEstadoRegistrado;
                document.getElementById("fechaEstadoActual").innerHTML = response.operacion.atc[0].fechaEstadoActual;



            }

        }).fail(function (response) {
            document.getElementById("mensajeatc").innerHTML = "Sin respuesta de Servicios Web Sat";

        });
```

Mi pregunta es como corregirlo y donde coloco el codigo de encabezado "Access-Control-Allow-Headers","*" Gracias

Comment: Dentro de `headers`

Comment: Tengo un sintaxis error al escribir "Access-Control-Allow-Headers","*"

Comment: Es `:` no `,`. Yo lo tengo así: `"Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "x-requested-with"`

Comment: "headers": {

                "Authorization": "Basic  asdfadsf",
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                "Accept": "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
                "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept",
                'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE'

            }

agregue este codigo pero aun sigo dando el mismo error

Comment: En tu sitio debes tener instalado un certificado de seguridad y acceder desde protocolo seguro `https://`, de lo contrario, seguirás obteniendo ese mensaje de error.

Comment: Las politicas CORS deben ser configuradas en el servidor... no en el cliente... Entonces o el servidor no esta permitiendo consultas desde su dominio... o depronto el servidor está mal configurado y esta devolviendo una cabecera de CORS mal formateada

Answer (score 0):

Creo que tu problema está más enfocado en el server.

Si tienes un Apache mira este enlace , si no dime y vemos.

No obstante cabe la posibilidad que el backend de tu app esté en Java con Spring o similar. En estos casos se puede configurar los CORS de una manera programatica en tu proyecto.

En enlace que te comento:
https://ubiq.co/tech-blog/enable-cors-apache-web-server/

Saludos!

Comment: Que tal mi servidor es Weblogic de Oracle y si el backend de mi web esta en Java pero puro